# Electromagnetic farady's law direction

Tags: electromagnetic, line, faradays-law

I have a question about direction of vectoral line integral in formula of electric potential and electric field.

- In electrostatic I assumed \$B\$ is positive potential and \$A\$ is negative potential so the boundary of the integral is negative to positive and also there is a minus sign outside the integral, and also \$d\ell\$ direction is always positive. This approach was always true in my electromagnetic 1 class.  For example if electric field is negative in the y-direction it means that the upper side is more positive and the lower side is more negative through the y-axis.

[image]

-But In electromagnetic 2 according to Faraday's law, time varying magnetic fields create emf. But this time the line integral is closed loop and I am very confused, what should I choose?  Which direction is positive and negative and where is the minus sign of the integral? For example if path is a circular loop
between 0 to 2\$\pi\$ how can I decide the positive and negative direction 0 to 2\$\pi\$ or 2\$\pi\$ to 0 and where is the minus sign?

[image]

Comment: Counter-clockwise is positive direction (remember this from trigonometry: how the angles are placed on the unit circle). Also remember the right hand rule.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting E around the closed loop will be in such a polarity as to produce a current that would, in turn, produce a changing flux that opposes the changing flux that caused the E.

[Lenz’s law](https://em.geosci.xyz/content/maxwell1_fundamentals/formative_laws/lenz.html) tells us that “Nature abhors a changing flux”.